# Why do websites use a graphic instead of the HTML entity `&equiv;` for the menu icon?

Tags: icons, menu

Every time I see a website with a menu or a navigation bar, i see the *three dash menu button*?. And they always use an icon, `.gif`, `.png` etc... But there is an [HTML entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) for that: `&equiv;` -> ≡. Since it's an HTML entity you can style it the way you want.

Why don't people use `&equiv;` for their website/Projects?

Comment: There's also ☰, the trigram for Heaven, that could be used as a text alternative to the icon. However, you can't really do anything with it. The company I work for actually uses three `div` elements to make the icon, as these can then be nicely animated into an ✖ icon by fading the middle one and rotating the outer two - can't do that with text *or* an image!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Do you have an example? I'd like to see that!

Comment: @Ian http://paragon.net.uk/ - the menu at the top-right has a slightly older version of the animation, but it's the same idea.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: That's a really nice effect :)

Comment: Why didn’t you use “→” instead of “->”. :)

Comment: @Ian The toggle-burger is also used on the 'all sections' action of the [new Guardian design](http://www.theguardian.com/us)

Comment: @RogerAttrill: :) Love the fact that they provide a humans.txt file too!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Using text rather than an image is good design **when displaying text**. This allows the user to interact with the text as text, doing things like copy and paste, or using alternative methods of reading the site content.

However, this menu button **is not actually text**.  It has nothing to do with the meaning of that text character (a mathematical symbol meaning "equivalent to").  Its resemblance to this character is purely coincidental.

Displaying it as text rather than an image has no clear benefit.  In fact, it may confuse someone using a screen reader.  An image with alt text describing it is the clear, correct choice.  Also, it would be more work to get the style right using the character.

Comment: "Displaying it as text rather than an image has no benefit." - Not quite true. Images require additional bandwidth (minor, admittedly). Images require multiple versions if you need different sizes or colors for the (otherwise) same image.

I'm not suggesting these advantages outweigh the accessibility concerns; I'm just pointing out your hyperbole.

Comment: @thelr, I have edited to allow the possibility of extremely trivial benefits.

Comment: Question: Does your answer mean I'm right to object to "ico-fonts"?

Comment: I don't think there's anything with wrong with icon-fonts. With some trickery you can get screenreaders to ignore them and attach text to the element that the screenreader _will_ read. Then you get all the benefits of a vector based icon that you can scale and color as you please via CSS.

Answer (score 11):

For branding purposes! It’s much easier to get the layout you want creating an image in your favorite design tool, than to tweak the supposed to be character with letter-spacing, margin, border, padding and font-size, which may look awful, if users zoom in to the site. You have much more control of an image than a font character.

[image]

Image by Nick Meloy posted originally on [Dribble](https://dribbble.com/shots/852180-Hamburger-Buttons)

Comment: The CSS may look awful if a user zooms in, but with proper attention, may tolerate zooming just fine. On the other hand, an image will always look pixellated when a user zooms in, unless it's vector (SVG).